# Comparing two values from GetValue reflection method

Tags: c#, reflection

I am getting `value1` and `value2` which are both zero as not equal when they should be the same.

How else can I compare the values of these 2 objects?

```
private bool CheckProjectIsUnique(
    TBR.Domain.Project project,
    List<UniqueProjectType> types,
    out UniqueProjectType uniqueCandidate)
{
    uniqueCandidate = CreateUniqueProjectType(project);

    if (types.Count == 0)
        return true;

    foreach (UniqueProjectType type in types)
    {
        bool exists = true;
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in type.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            var value1 = prop.GetValue(type, null);
            var value2 = prop.GetValue(uniqueCandidate, null);
             if (value1 != value2)
             {
                 exists = false;
                 break;
             }
        }
        if (exists)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 21):

They are objects, so you should use `value1.Equals(value2)` with checking if `value1` is not `null`

**EDIT:** Better: use static `Object.Equals(value1, value2)` (credits to @LukeH)

Comment: Or use that static `object.Equals(value1,value2)` method which will handle the null checking for you.

Answer (score 4):

Equals is inherited from System.Object and it won't ensure that both objects would be correctly compared if you don't provide your own implementation of Equals.

Override System.Object.Equals and/or implement `IEquatable<T>` in your domain objects or any object you want to eval its equality with another one.

Learn more reading this article:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1.equals?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: The OP is using the non-polymorphic `!=` operator on `object`, so it doesn't matter whether or not you override `Equals` or implement `IEquatable<T>`, the OP's code is testing for reference (in)equality.

Comment: But he's trying to eval if value1 and value2 equals. This isn't about references, it is? :D

Comment: Or if I'm wrong, then he needs to compose a better question, because he would need to specify if he wants a reference or value equality.

Answer (score 3):

Swap `if (value1 != value2)` for `if (!object.Equals(value1, value2))` and you should be good to go.

The `!=` operator that you're currently using is non-virtual, and since the compile-time type of the `GetValue` calls is `object` you'll always be testing for reference (in)equality.

Using the static [`object.Equals(x,y)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k.aspx) method instead tests first for reference equality, and if the objects aren't the same reference will then defer to the virtual [`Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) method.

Answer (score 1):

If the type of the property is a value type (like int for example), the value returned by GetValue will be boxed into an object. Then `==` will compare the references of these boxed values. If you want to have a correct comparison, you should use the Equals method:

```
class Program
{
    class Test
    {
        public int A { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var testA = new Test { A = 1 };
        var testB = new Test { A = 1 };

        var propertyInfo = typeof(Test).GetProperties().Where(p => p.Name == "A").Single();

        var valueA = propertyInfo.GetValue(testA, null);
        var valueB = propertyInfo.GetValue(testB, null);

        var result = valueA == valueB; // False
        var resultEquals = valueA.Equals(valueB); // True

    }
}
```